# Fragment doing hard work?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I have this fragment, that on creating lags the main UI thread. I put the content loader into asynctask, but it still laggs a bit. Should I put work with geocoder class into separate thread ? https://github.com/lupajz/bc/blob/master/app/src/com/kulturnepodujatia/fragments/AroundMeFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

ah, I have just found out that geocoder uses Internet for lookups :P so new thread for that should do the trick. solved

Comment: If its in UI Thread, you should had a NetworkOnMainThreadException... all google products need to communicate with their servers and the geocoder is also limited. Check it out for your needs.